# How to access a local variable from outside the function in node.js

Tags: node.js, variables, local

All I am trying here is to access the local variable 'htmlrows' outside the function but it seems its not that easy with node.js.

```
var htmlrows;
query.on('row', function(row) {    
  console.log("%s  |%s |%d",    row.empid,row.name,row.age); 
  htmlrows += "<tr><td>" + row.empid + "</td><td>" +row.name + "</td><td>" +row.age + "</td></tr>";

});

console.log("htmlrows outside function");
console.log(htmlrows); // console log prints 'undefined'.
```

Could you please let me know how to access 'htmlrows' outside the function?

Thanks much in advance

Comment: Why not apply the logic inside the function, where the result is returned?

Comment: Thanks Ben for the quick response. As you said rightly that is a possibility but I would like to access is outside the function.Just for my learning if I really wanted to access outside the function how would i do it?

Comment: Assuming there's an `end` event in the instance of `EventEmitter` which is `query` (this is typical): `query.on('row',function(row){...htmlrows += "...";}).on('end',function(){console.log(htmlrows);});`

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that node.js is asynchronous, so `console.log(htmlrows);` is being executed before the query function has completed.

What you need to do is have a separate function that listens for a callback from the query function.

You could try using the async middleware for node.js, which will allow you to chain async calls in series, so that they get executed in a certain order:

```
var some_data = null;
async.series([
    function(callback) {
      //...do a thing
      function_1(callback);
    },
    function(callback) {
      //...do another thing
      function_2(callback);
    }
    //...etc
]);

function function_1(callback) {
    some_data = 'value';
    console.log('function_1!');
    return callback();
}

function function_2(callback) {
    console.log('function_2: '+some_data);
    return callback();
}
```

will result in:

```
#:~ function_1!
#:~ function_2: value
```